# Converting MATLAB random function to python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

My task is to convert one big MATLAB file into python.

There is a line in MATLAB

```
weightsEI_slow = random('binom',1,0.2,[EneuronNum_slow,IneuronNum_slow]);
```

I am trying to convert this into python code, I am not quite finding the right documentation. I looked for numpy library too. Does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: What is `EneuronNum_slow` and `IneuronNum_slow`? and `weightsEI_slow` ?

Comment: Their variables and their values are 800 and 200 respectively for my purpose.

Comment: You should complement your question by describing the expected behavior, otherwise those who don't use this function can't help

Comment: I'm sorry, Totaly new to this platform. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you generate a random number that follows the Binomial distribution with probability `p=0.2` and sample size `n=1`. In turn, you can leverage numpy

```
import numpy as np

np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.2)
>0
```

If you require replicability, add `np.random.seed(3408)` before the number is sampled. Otherwise, the output might be `0` or `1` depending on the execution. Of course, you can switch in another integer value as the seed instead of `3408`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering my question. 

The matlab code that I am converting has poor comments. The matlab code ```weightsEI_slow = random('binom',1,0.2,[EneuronNum_slow,IneuronNum_slow]); ``` has `[EneuronNum_slow, IneuronNum_slow]` part which I did not understand in matlab code.

 EneuronNum_slow has a value of 800 and IneuronNum_slow has a value of 200. 

do I not need to add those parts to the python code that you mentioned above?
```import numpy as np

np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.2)
>0```

Comment: As Rodrigo Laguna pointed out, you don't describe the expected behavior. Moreover, the function `random(...)` looks not like a typical MATLAB random number generator as found in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binomial-distribution.html). In turn, it is impossible for us to guess the functionality that is supposed to be implemented in Python.